# Cursor movement through face center?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, motion-detection

I'm creating an application in which the user will use their face to move the mouse. I have used Emgucv (wrapper for opencv) to create an application in C# which detects the face of a person and locates the center-point on their face.
I'm using the `setcursorpos` function to move the cursor. What I'm doing is I'm passing the center coordinates of the face detection to `setcursorpos`, so the mouse movement is very limited.

How do I move the mouse anywhere on the screen smoothly by the slightest face movement?

Comment: There is another application [`Opengazer`](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/opengazer/) which uses eye for mouse control. Have a look on it. Atleast you will get an idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [a c# tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTm0P-u0HKI) on youtube where (source code included) where I show
how to detect head movement direction.

Basically it makes use of opencv goodfeaturestotrack and then use optical flow to compute the overall motion from a set of points.

Comment: Andy, take a look at eViacam, an application that does exactly what you want to. Ask their authors, or look up their source. Get some hints. Its on SourceForge